# Which is more efficient? A nested if in a for loop or a separate if with a separate for loop?

Tags: python, performance, loops

So I'm trying to decide which of these is more efficient, or if there is a difference between them. The program I'm writing iterates through a for loop (python) and does some stuff, and then, depending on a flag, will write to a file.

Example A:

```
for element in list:
    Do stuff
    if(write_to_file):
       write to file
```

Vs example B:

```
for element in list:
    Do stuff
if(write_to_file):
    for element in list:
        write to file
```

In the case of A it has to check every time if it's true, but in the case of B if it is true it has to then re-do the for loop. My thought is that they're equal, but I'd like opinions of more experienced programmers

Comment: You are writing to a file, ergo, you are worrying over something that'll fall into nothingness compared to the time the I/O takes. :-)

Comment: Use timeit and find out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: There's no substitute for [testing it yourself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: @IanAuld, Henry Keiter: Thanks, I didn't know that function existed. Will do

Comment: check out ipython if you haven't yet...

Comment: Depending on what `Do stuff` actually does, the two may have different semantics, in which case the timing differences are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity analysis of your example(s):

```
for element in list:
    Do stuff
if(write_to_file):
    for element in list:
        write to file
```

The above is less efficient because you are iterating over `list` twice.

i.e: `O(n) x 2`

But please test yourself, use the `timeit` module and most importantly of all you are worrying prematurely about optimization. *get it working first!*

Read also: [When to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: If `write_to_file` is false, this is *more* efficient, because there's only a single loop iteration *and* the condition is checked only once, rather than each time through the loop.

Comment: Except for when it's ``True``. Yes it all depends. The OP has not provided any specifics so this is the best answer I can provide based on what I see :)

Comment: @JamesMills, it's based on user input so completely random. Based on your input and the input in the comments on the OP I tried using timeit on it:

Example A:
Write_to_file = false: 18.05 ms
write_to_file = true:  18.60 ms

Ex B:
Write to file = true:19.4 ms
Writeto file = false: 18.27 ms

Not much difference. And don't worry, it was working before I asked!

Comment: @musher: user input is anything but completely random!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm actually curious about this - what do you mean?

Comment: I just mean that users tend to take common paths through your app, though they're not always the paths you expect. I guess you're not writing a business-critical system, but when you are you should analyse and optimise the most critical features. IOW, if testing shows that users choose to save the file 95% of the time, that's the option you should try to make fast.

Answer (score 1):

Example C:

```
if(write_to_file):
    for element in list:
        Do stuff
        write to file
else:
    for element in list:
        Do stuff
```

As others have said, you will probably not be able notice the difference between any of these approaches.